# Advice on asking a question − How to setup a Honeypot?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

I want to post the follow question, but because there are several questions that are similar. This is different because i'm asking for the details of a walk through procedure of setting it up. I'm willing to offer a bounty to make it worth the effort for the person who answers it. But I don't want to get flagged for a dup. Opinions?

> I know that we have several 'set up honeypot' threads.
>
> - [Setting up a honeypot](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/setting-up-a-honeypot)
> - [Honeypot on home network to help me learn](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/honeypot-on-home-network-to-help-me-learn?rq=1)
> - [How to operate a honeypot in the cloud?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/how-to-operate-a-honeypot-in-the-cloud?rq=1)
>
> But none of these are a walk through for noobs. What I'm looking for a Step by Step guide to setting up a honey pot. Here is what i'm looking for in a 'good' answer;
>
> - OS configuration (Windows/Linux/Virtual set up procedures)
> - Network Configuration (DMZ's, Port Forwards, Network Lockdown procedures)
> - Software usage & Configuration (http://www.honeynet.org/project)
> - Post-exploitation Analyses (What do I do with all these logs and files?!)
> - Any other key points that most NOOBS will most likely miss..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds more like a book than a question.

[How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work) is really the limit of how verbose we want to be. I think this question with the detail you've outlined would be longer. If you split each of those bullets as a very security focused question, I think that would work here.

If you did manage to complete the series on the site, compiling them all would make for a good blog article at the end.

Comment: Good call. Guess its time to refine it.

Comment: A blogpost is a good idea actually

Comment: Good idea on the blog article.  Unfortunately, it seems it's going to be very tricky to get this question so that it's both reasonably scoped *and* applicable to a wide audience.  Even the broken-up versions look like they could be chapters in a book, or volumes in a series.

Comment: Agree on the overly wide scope. Moreover, @DigitalFire, I think that several of these broken-down chapters would be better on [su], rather than here - e.g. setting up your OS, network configuration, etc.